# Getting absolute control of a table's width

Tags: mobile, html-table

I'm building an app that will be viewed on mobile and laptops.
When viewed on mobile, the table is getting cut off on the right side, and fine on laptop.
I've tried inline styling with

```
<table width="350px">
```

and trying settings with:

```
<table style="....">
```

I've tried a fair number of options and combos, but nothing is working.
Can anyone provide some general guidance on how to get absolute control over a table's width, or provide clear general guideline(s) that control a table's width?

Answer (score 0):

This absolutely controls a table's width:

```
<table style="max-width:250px; table-layout: fixed;">
<tr>
<td style="max-width: 220px; word-wrap:break-word;">
<td style="max-width: 30px; word-wrap:break-word;">
```